# "Package HttpClient does not exist" when compiling

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, httpclient

I am attempting to compile EWSJavaAPI1.5 in Eclipse and in IntelliJ. I have had no luck. I keep getting a `org.apache.commons.httpclient does not exist` error. Its driving me nuts. I added the four required files:

- commons-codec-1.4.jar
- commons-httpcliient-3.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- jcifs-1.3.15.jar

The four jar files are being referenced, yet it does not find the httpclient when compiling. It may have to do with the class path but I am not sure if I am adding it to the class path correctly. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the library classpath is set correctly and this library is added to the [dependencies of your module](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html). Another possible case could be corrupted jar file, try to download it again.